# Compiling tesseract-ocr on ARM/Gumstix?

Tags: embedded, ocr, embedded-linux, tesseract, gumstix

Is it possible to compile [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) for the [Intel PXA270](http://www.intel.com/design/embeddedpca/applicationsprocessors/302302.htm) found in certain [Gumstix](http://www.gumstix.com/) boards?  Has anyone done this successfully, and if so, how did you do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does seem doable. This bug report on cross compiling tesseract-ocr for ARM ends with a workaround and the claim that it works from there on: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=262

Comment: That worked, had to change one more line in that Makefile for the path to the cross-compile ar as well, thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! Do feedback your patches to the project so that more can enjoy it! and Merry Christmas!